# changing the clusters order for k means result

Tags: r, k-means

I'm running a k means test in R (`kmeans()`) on two attributes measured for a list of samples.
Something along these line:
`df<-data.frame(Sample=c("S1","S2","S3","S4","S5"),VarA=scale(sample(1:10,5,replace = T)),VarB=scale(sample(runif(5))))`
The variables are scaled for the `kmeans()` function.
Based on `fviz_nbclust()` in the package `EnvStats` I devide it in 3 clusters
I then run `VarAK<-kmeans(df$VarA,3,nstart = 25)` and `VarBK<-kmeans(df$VarB,3,nstart = 25)`.
My goal is to run a fishers test and see if the two variables correlate.
My issue is that when I run the test on each variable the clusters don't match. For VarA the clusters are 1=highest and 3=lowest and for VarB the clusters are 1=lowest and 2=highest.
Any ideas on how to set the clusters' order?
Thanks

Comment: I found a useful answer on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906180/consistent-cluster-order-with-kmeans-in-r)

Comment: Does the above link answer your question? Should this post be marked as a duplicate of that post?